# Window styles / Minimal titlebar/borders

Tags: windows, winapi, coding-style, window-style

I'm looking for some kind of a resource (website) that would list all possible window/dialog frame styles and their respective combinations *with images*. I'm only really interested in Vista, as my software won't support older platforms anyway.

I have a more specific case here too: I'm wondering if there are other ways to achieve a smaller-than-normal titlebar for my window than `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW`? The tool window style would otherwise suit my needs, but in addition to the normal window border, it seems to add this one-pixel wide white border inside the black outline, and that just looks really ugly for my purposes.

I remember older versions of Adobe Photoshop (CS2?) having these ridiculously tiny titlebars on the tool windows, like 8-10px wide. I'm wondering if those can be done with normal winapi, since IIRC they came in vista flavour too, and conformed to whatever windows skin was in use..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's Vista-only, you can try to use your own window decoration and use the [Desktop Window Manager (DWM) API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969540.aspx) to still provide Aero Glass Theming.

On the other hand, if you're targeting Vista and later, you'll most likely not have to deal with low resolutions. Don't think too much about a few pixels more or less.